# Hypersurfaces in gransmannians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

**NOTICE:** This is not a question about research.

Hi guys. I'm studying Chow forms from the book **Discriminants, Resultants, and Multidimensional Determinants** of Andrei Zelevinsky and Izrail' Moiseevič Gel'fand. In order to introduce Chow forms the authors prove this proposition.

[image]
[image]

There is something I don't understand and that of course some algebraic geometers can explain me.

(i) The authors use the term *generic pencil* when they define the degree. What is the precise meaning of the word generic? Where  can I find more about the definition of degree of hypersurfaces in grasmannians?

(ii) To prove that the restriction of the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)$ to $P_{NM}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$ the author claim that it suffices to prove that any section of $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)$ has a exactly a zero on $P_{NM}$. Why?

[image]

Comment: i) : the term generic pencil in $G(k,n)$ means the following. Take two generic $\mathbb{C}^{k-1}$ (say M) and a generic $\mathbb{C}^{k+1}$, say $N$ in the fixed $\mathbb{C}^n$. <<Generic>> means that there are Zariski open subsets of $G(k-1,n)$ and $G(k+1,n)$ where the choices of $M$ and $N$ can be made in. Then the set of $\mathbb{C}^k$ containing $M$ and contained in $N$ is easily seen to be a $\mathbb{P}^1$.

Comment: ii) : We know that $\mathrm{Pic}(\mathbb{P}^1) = \mathbb{Z}$, hence to determine $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)|_{P_{MN}}$, we only have to find the degree of an effective divisor representing $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)|_{P_{MN}}$. A section of $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)$ naturally restricts to a section of $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)|_{P_{MN}}$. If the zero locus of the restricted section vanishes exactly in one point, then the corresponding effective divisor is a point, that is a divisor of degree $1$. Means that $\mathcal{O}_{G(k,n)}(1)|_{P_{MN}} = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$.